# avoid repetition of "information"

Tags: letter-writing, repetition

I am writing letter of confirmation and I don`t know how to avoid repetition of word information in these sentences:

Thank you for this information.
I am writing to confirm that I received information about travel support.

Comment: If you reverse the sentences, you could replace the second _information_ with a pronoun: "I am writing to confirm that I received information about travel support; thank you for sending _it_."

Comment: Proofreading and writing advice questions are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker. The only exception is when there is a clearly identified source of concern about an element of the English language that would be interesting and useful to many future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"...to confirm that I received your submission..."

Edit— better answer is in the comments:

Say "Thank you for the information." That statement alone also conveys that you received the information, and doesn't have to be repeated. Or "I received the information you sent. Thank you."

Comment: Is submission correct word? Because I need to confirm that I got information about allowed travel support for me.

Comment: Well, you ARE repeating yourself. Perhaps the better answer is simply to say "Thank you for the information."  That statement alone also conveys that you received the information, and doesn't have to be repeated.  Or "I received the information you sent. Thank you."

Comment: I don't think that "submission" is the right word for what the OP has described; your suggestion in the comments is better than your answer.

Comment: Vanderpn — agreed. The real answer is in the comment

Answer (score 0):

*'Thank you for sending this information about travel support'*, will do normally. If needed, phrases like 'useful', 'very useful', 'valuable' etc. can be added before 'information'.

"Brevity is beautiful".